# How to click on hidden select under button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

I need to select a URL value, but I don't understand how to do it

```
<span class="select select_layout_content select_size_s select_theme_normal
queries-filter-item__indicator i-bem select_js_inited _popup-destructor 
_popup-destructor_js_inited" 
data-bem="{&quot;select&quot;:{&quot;live&quot;:false}}" title="">
    <button class="button button_arrow_down button_theme_normal button_size_s select__button i-bem button_js_inited" type="button" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{}}">
    <span class="button__text" aria-hidden="true">Total shows</span>
</button>
<select class="select__control" id="uniq16686900391151" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option class="select__option" value="TOTAL_SHOWS_COUNT" selected="selected">Total shows</option>
<option class="select__option" value="TOTAL_CLICKS_COUNT">Clicks count</option>
<option class="select__option" value="AVERAGE_SHOW_POSITION">Average Position</option>
<option class="select__option" value="TOTAL_CTR">CTR, %</option>
<option class="select__option" value="URL">URL</option>
<option class="select__option" value="QUERY">Text</option>
</select>
</span>
```

My code (the last command) get "Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"

```
    # Click on make filter - is works
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/span/span").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Click on select button - is works
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/span[1]/button").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # Click on URL option
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/span[1]/select/option[5]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with the element that has the attribute `aria-hidden="true"`.
There is a special class in Selenium for the `select` elements. First, you need to import the `Select` class. You can try to use this code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# Click on make filter - is works
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/span/span").click()
time.sleep(1)
# Click on select button - is works
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/span[1]/button").click()
time.sleep(5)
# Click on URL option
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'uniq16686900391151'))
dropdown.select_by_value('URL')
```

Comment: Unfortunately((
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="uniq16686900391151"]"}

Comment: Can you check if this id has a permanent value on the page?

Comment: ID of selector is always different, but i also used By.XPATH and got "Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="button button_size_m button_theme_action form__submit i-bem button_js_inited" type="submit" autocomplete="off" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{}}">...</button> is not clickable at point (564, 301). Other element would receive the click: <span class="select__text">...</span>"

Comment: '''
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/span[1]/select"))
dropdown.select_by_value('URL')
'''